# Procedural Generation of object with random transformation

Tags: modifiers, transforms, procedural, transform-orientation

I am new to blender, so what I am asking may be a very simple thing to do. I am trying to procedurally generate multiples of an object and apply random transformations to it. I have a simple curve and want to generate multiple copies of it while also varying the copies scaling and translation. I have been playing with the particle effects option, but it doesn't seem to be working to what I want. And the array modifier has each of them spaced apart. I am trying to have them overlayed on top of each directly so that when the transformations are applied I have more control over the anchoring point for all the curves, and I not been able to find something that generates objects between two points of anchors.

Comment: did you try a hair particle system with Vertices as source? This way you can first define the exact location of your particles using a Mesh, Grid  or else, then use the Advanced check box of the ParticleSystem and tweak the Rotation/Phase?

Comment: What vertex would I choose as the source though, the main curve itself? All that happens when I do that is that curves just emit (as "hairs") from random vertices of the main object. Should I make a new mesh as a single vertex and choose that?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your scene or object? You're mentioning objects in your post then curve as source... this is a bit confusing. Screenshots would also go a long way to help you get an answer.